# How to properly package a project with Setuptools in Python?

Tags: python, package, setuptools, setup.py

Here is my directory tree:

```
prediction_model
├─ prediction_model
|  ├─ __init__.py
|  ├─ data
|  |  ├─ SAAA.csv
|  |  └─ VDFF.csv
|  ├─ models.py
|  ├─ preprocess.py
|  ├─ README.md
|  └─ tests
└─ setup.py
```

Here is my ‘setup.py’:

```py
from setuptools import find_packages, setup

setup(
    name='prediction_model',
    version='0.7',
    url='https://project.org/',
    author='JL',
    author_email='jl@project.org',
    packages=find_packages(),
    scripts=['models.py', 'preprocess.py']
)
```

Here is my ‘__init__.py’:

```py
from prediction_model import models
from prediction_model import preprocess
```

‘models.py’ has a function `main` and ‘preprocess.py’ has a function `run` that I want to use.

I install the project using:

```sh
python -m pip install --user .
```

Then I run the following code in the Python interpreter but it raises an exception `AttributeError`:

```py
>>> import prediction_model
>>> prediction_model.src.main()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'prediction_model' has no attribute 'src'
>>> prediction_model.src.run()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'prediction_model' has no attribute 'src'
```

```py
>>> import prediction_model
>>> prediction_model.main()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'prediction_model' has no attribute 'main'
>>> prediction_model.run()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'prediction_model' has no attribute 'run'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Environment: Python 3.7, MacOS.

Comment: After installation, when you do `import prediction_model` in your client code, it runs implicitly the \_\_init\_\_.py file. Since in it you do `from prediction_model import preprocess, models`, the `preprocess` and `models` modules will be in your namespace. Then instead of doing `prediction_model.src.main()` in your client code which raises an `AttributeError` since there is no `src` object in your namespace, you should just do `prediction_model.preprocess.run()` and `prediction_model.models.main()`.

Comment: If instead you wanted to do `prediction_model.run()` and `prediction_model.main()` in your client code, you should do `from prediction_model.preprocess import run; from prediction_model.models import main` in your \_\_init\_\_.py file.

Comment: Another thing, your `scripts` argument should be `['prediction_model/models.py', 'prediction_model/preprocess.py']` instead of `['models.py', 'preprocess.py']` (since relative paths are resolved against the directory of setup.py). In addition the models.py and preprocess.py files need a shebang line at their top or the installation will fail: `#!/usr/bin/env python`. But since they are *Python* scripts and are part of the `prediction_model` package, you should use the `entry_points` argument instead of the `scripts` argument and you won’t need this shebang line.

Answer (score 3):

## Set up

The best practice is to use the *src layout* (cf. https://blog.ionelmc.ro/2014/05/25/python-packaging/), so I suggest that you organize your directories like this (since you should not package the ‘tests’ directory and ‘README.rst’ file for built distribution, they are left outside the ‘src’ directory):

```
project
├─ src
|  └─ package
|     ├─ __init__.py
|     ├─ __main__.py
|     ├─ data.tsv
|     └─ module.py
├─ tests
|  └─ test_module.py
├─ MANIFEST.in
├─ README.rst
└─ setup.py
```

with the following ‘setup.py’ file contents:

```py
import setuptools

setuptools.setup(
    name="project name",
    version="project version",
    url="project URI",
    author="your name",
    author_email="your email",
    package_dir={"": "src"},
    packages=setuptools.find_namespace_packages(where="src"),
    include_package_data=True
)
```

and the following ‘MANIFEST.in’ file contents:

```
graft src
graft tests
global-exclude *.py[cod]
```

*Remark.* — If you don't want a top-level ‘package’ directory in your ‘src’ directory while keeping the ‘src’ directory (like before your post edit):

```
project
├─ src
|  ├─ __init__.py
|  ├─ __main__.py
|  ├─ data.tsv
|  └─ module.py
├─ tests
|  └─ test_module.py
├─ MANIFEST.in
├─ README.rst
└─ setup.py
```

then map `"package"` to `"src"` in the `package_dir` argument and list `"package"` explicitly in the `packages` argument of the `setuptools.setup` function in the setup.py file (cf. https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/examples.html#pure-python-distribution-by-package):

```py
import setuptools

setuptools.setup(
    name="project name",
    version="project version",
    url="project URI",
    author="your name",
    author_email="your email",
    package_dir={"package": "src"},
    packages=["package"],
    include_package_data=True
)
```

## Package

Now you can package the project into a *source* distribution with this command:

```sh
python setup.py sdist
```

or a *built* distribution with this command (this is an extension command to `setuptools` requiring that `wheel` be installed in your Python environment—so run `pip install wheel` before):

```sh
python setup.py bdist_wheel
```

or both with this command:

```sh
python setup.py sdist bdist_wheel
```

which create the following files in a new `dist` directory:

- ‘{project name}-{project version}.tar.gz’ for a source distribution;
- ‘{project name}-{project version}-{compatibility tags}.whl’ for a built distribution.

## Install

Now you can install the project from the source distribution with this command:

```sh
pip install dist/{project name}-{project version}.tar.gz
```

or from the built distribution with this command:

```sh
pip install dist/{project name}-{project version}-{compatibility tags}.whl
```

or from the project tree with this command (no need to package the project for this one):

```sh
pip install .
```

## Run

Eventually you can import your project like this:

```py
import package.module

package.module.function()
```

Comment: It's not really a _src_ layout. They just named their top level package `src`. And I believe they expect it to be importable under the name of the project `prediction_model`, which of course doesn't work.

Comment: That's a good edit. I removed my downvote. Why the `find_namespace_packages` instead of `find_packages`? Isn't it a bit misleading?

Comment: Thanks. `find_namespace_packages` is the modern version of `find_packages` (which should not be used anymore) since it supports implicit namespace packages introduced in Python 3.3 (cf. https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#find-namespace-packages).

Comment: From my point of view, too many unrelated details now (`MANIFEST.in`, `include_package_data`), _wheels_, etc.). Why not just focus on the original issue: wrong name of the top level package. A link to a well established reference for the general packaging guidelines would have been enough for the extra details. Even though everything seems like good advice.

Comment: @sinoroc Actually without `MANIFEST.in` and `include_package_data=True` non `.py` files (like the asker's `.csv` files) will *not* be included in the packaged/installed project, so they are necessary (cf. https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#including-data-files). An alternative is to use the `package_data` argument but it is only used for *built* distributions so you still have to use `MANIFEST.in` for *source* distributions; since it duplicates information it is discouraged (cf. https://blog.ionelmc.ro/presentations/packaging/#slide:15).

Comment: someones blog is not the source of truth, https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/ (The src dir is a very javaish thing, not very pythonic, and not very common either AFAIK)

Comment: @E.Serra A lot of major Python projects use the `src` layout now: [Flask](https://github.com/pallets/flask), [Sentry](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry), [Pillow](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow), [Pip](https://github.com/pypa/pip), [Werkzeug](https://github.com/pallets/werkzeug), [GEvent](https://github.com/gevent/gevent), [PyTest](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest), [Marshmallow](https://github.com/marshmallow-code/marshmallow), [Twisted](https://github.com/twisted/twisted), [Pyramid](https://github.com/Pylons/pyramid), [Cryptography](https://github.com/pyca/cryptography).

Comment: @E.Serra And a few major Python projects have adopted the `lib` layout: [Ansible](https://github.com/ansible/ansible), [SQLAlchemy](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy). The PyPA will soon update the tutorial to recommend the `src` layout (cf. https://github.com/pypa/packaging.python.org/issues/320).

Comment: lib layout makes me want to puke, no wonder ansible is such a mess, a lot of projects still use the non src notation, and there is nothing wrong with it, I take your src thing as a valid argument, but not as the prefered/official one (And you can not state the recommended one is that one because it is NOT)

Answer (score 0):

usual project structure: (Long story short you WANT a directory with your project name for setup.py to get it, this is the usual way, take a look at a couple repos, e.g. https://github.com/boto/boto3 ).

```
-- setup.py
-- README.md
--- prediction_model
    |-- __init__.py
    |-- data
    |   |-- VDFF.csv
    |   +-- SAAA.csv
    |-- models.py
    |-- preprocess.py
    |-- tests
    +-- _data.csv
```

Then you want to do something like:

```
virtualenv myvirtualenv 
source myvirtualenv/bin/activate
python setup.py install
```

Your setup looks fine, now prediction_model is a package you can also change:

```
from . import preprocess
from . import models
```

To

```
from prediction_model import preprocess
from prediction_model import models
```

Normal setup.py

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name='cost_estimation',
    version='0.0.1',
    packages=find_packages(),
    url='http://github.com/<WHATEVER/WHATEVER>',
    install_requires=[
        'numpy',
    ],
    tests_require=[
         'nosetests',
    ],
    test_suite='nose.collector',
    license='',
    dependency_links=[
        'http://YOURPRIVATEPYPISERVER/packages'
    ],

    keywords='models, prediction',
    author='your name',
    description='Model prediction cool stuff'
)
```

Comment: https://python-packaging-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setup_py.html
`pip install .` equivalent to `python -m pip install --user .`, develop mode. I for some reason need to use root authority for install.

Comment: plus..`ImportError: No module named setuptools` always returns although I can import this module when I load python. I just don't get this.

Comment: Using the same name, doesn't confuse the packaging tools? This setuptools is useless anway, doesn't seem to find packages through `find_packages()`

Comment: Fro my point of view there are some superfluous (and possibly misleading details) in this answer, but basically, yes, that looks like a correct answer. In short, rename your `src` directory to the name you want to be able to import i.e. `prediction_model`. Note that it doesn't have to be the same name as the name of the project (the one in `setup.py`).

Comment: But thank you for guiding me in the right direction @sinoroc and @E.Serra. Trying smth, at least got a start. now the scripts are called. `prediction_model.preprocess.run()`, `prediction_model.models.main()` like this. with many other error.

Comment: Yes, it might be frustrating. Maybe uninstall the project `pip uninstall prediction_model`, make sure it is really uninstalled with `pip list`, find the `prediction_model.egg-info` directory in your source code directory, delete it, then install again. In case of doubt these steps often help with packaging issues.

Comment: ALWAYS USE A VIRTUALENV ALWAAAAYS. The n at the end of your development you do pip freeze and dump it into a requirements.txt and you are done :)
Never use pip with sudo etc